# How can I reduce the space between the texts?

Tags: html, text, space, anki

I use Anki program and I would like to reduce the space between 'Meaning', 'Example', 'Meaning2' and 'Example2'.

[Image here shows what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrxLi.jpg)

and my code:

```
.card {  
font-family: Arial;  
font-size: 20px;  
text-align: center;  
color: black;  
background-color: white;  
}
```

Comment: can you please put the code in a codepen or a jsfiddle? That would make it a lot easier for us to help you

Comment: http://codepen.io/Toda82/pen/MJbRjm

Comment: There are places where you haven't closed the <td> tags.

Comment: Also. The reason why there is a large space, is because that the td height where you have the image is 300px. That will automatically change the height of the td next to it, since it's a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra space between the rows, is because you have defined a height of 300px in the cell that contains the image. Since it's a table, the next cell will then inherit the height of 300px.

To avoid that, you need to make the image-cell to span two rows. You do that by adding `rowspan="2"` to you image-cell, and remove the empty cell on the second row.

Then you also should consider making the image 300px in height instead of the image-cell. Else you could end up with an unwanted result.

---

**Here I have made an illustration of your code:**
[image: Before]

> As you can se, when the image-cell, has an height of 300px the cell
>   next to it, will also have it, because cells in the same row cannot
>   have multiple heights. That's why there is so much space below the
>   text in the second cell.

**And here, if you use `rowspan`:**
[image: After]

> Now the image-cell have "merged" with the cell below it, so it
>   basically becomes one single cell. The cell next to it, no longer
>   inherits the height, so the space below the text disappears.

If you still have a height of 300px on the image-cell, the browser will try to fit all the content from the two rows, in that height. If that's not possible, the table will then expand to fit the content. So if you in the first place made the image-cell 300px in height so the image could fit that height, I would instead make the image itself that height.

If you want the text and images to align on the top, you can use `valign="top"` on all of the cells.

I would still recommend you to do all the style in a separate CSS-file and not inlined.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x9djsd4y/)

Comment: Woah, it looks great now :) Thank you all for your time and energy, have a nice day!